# Custom Query problem access the values

Tags: query

Below is the custom query am running on my wordpress site to get the results from postmeta table. When I `var_dump` the results then I can see the values correctly but when am trying to access a single field from the array, it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

```
    <?php
        $key = "sc_event_year";
        $value = $today_year;
        global $wpdb;       
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => $key, 'meta_value' => $value ) );
        //var_dump($query);
        foreach($query as $result){
            echo $result->post_id;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)?

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply. I have changed my code now. Now can you tell me what am doing wrong? I' am editing the new code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked for an array and you are trying to use an object.

```
$key = "sc_event_year";
$value = $today_year;
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'sc_event_year' AND meta_value = $value", ARRAY_A);
foreach ($results as $result){
    echo $post_id = $result['post_id']; // <-- here was the problem
}
```

Unless `$value` is a number you could have have trouble with that query and I can't tell if there is user-supplied data but `prepare` is pretty good habit if you are going to be cooking up your own queries.

```
$key = "sc_event_year";
$value = $today_year;
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'sc_event_year' AND meta_value = %s",
    $value
  ),
  ARRAY_A
);
foreach ($results as $result){
 echo $post_id = $result['post_id'];
}
```

That said, are you sure there are no Core functions or methods that will server your purpose?